Can you be Muslim even if you struggle to believe there is a god?
I was raised with the belief there isn't a god, I want to believe but my mind doesn't really let me. Can I still be Muslim/how can I start to truly believe?

study about Imam Hussain a.s. he can solve this problem now.

There is a point in that you want to believe but my mind doesn't really let you. Why do you want it? What is to rely more on, your heart or your mind?
According to Islam, believing in Islam is as easy as believing in any other obvious facts, and even easier ("أَفِي اللَّهِ شَكٌّ فَاطِرِ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ الْأَرْضِ يَدْعُوكُمْ لِيَغْفِرَ لَكُمْ مِنْ ذُنُوبِكُمْ وَ يُؤَخِّرَكُمْ إِلَيٰ أَجَلٍ مُسَمًّي" which means "Is there a doubt about Allah, The Creator of the heavens and the earth? It is He Who invites you, in order that He may forgive you your sins and give you respite for a term appointed!"), but you should also mention what is "obvious"? An obvious fact is what can be directly accepted without any reasoning, given that there is no obstacle in accepting it. As example let me tell you a joke:

A physicist once described the mathematicians as idiots! He was
criticized hardly for doing so, but elaborated his position like this:
A mathematician is someone who can accept only the "obvious" facts!

He was again criticized, even more. So he again clarified his position
by saying that:
the mathematician are those that when one of them shows a strange proposition to another one, and that another one finds it hardly

acceptable denies the result, then the former mathematician shows the
proof and the second one studied it for hours, until he reaches the
end of the proof and concludes "Yes you're right, it's obvious! How
com I didn't mention this from the very beginning!?"

All reasonings provided by Islamic Philosophers are to help people overcome their mental obstacles, and find what is obvious as indeed obvious. However, philosophical reasonings are not the only ways to do so, not even the best, to be more precise. The best way, as far as I have seen, is to live a healthy life, and indeed to keep our heart  healthy (إِلَّا مَنْ أَتَي اللَّهَ بِقَلْبٍ سَلِيمٍ). The wrongdoers who have darken their hearts will never find a way to overcome their doubts, even if they study philosophy for ages and even develop their own reasoning to prove God and the Day and etc. This is in Quran that those in doubt will enter the fire:

وَ لَوْ تَرَيٰ إِذْ فَزِعُوا فَلَا فَوْتَ وَ أُخِذُوا مِنْ مَكَانٍ
قَرِيبٍ * وَ قَالُوا آمَنَّا بِهِ وَ أَنَّيٰ لَهُمُ التَّنَاوُشُ مِنْ
مَكَانٍ بَعِيدٍ * وَ قَدْ كَفَرُوا بِهِ مِنْ قَبْلُ وَ يَقْذِفُونَ
بِالْغَيْبِ مِنْ مَكَانٍ بَعِيدٍ * وَ حِيلَ بَيْنَهُمْ وَ بَيْنَ مَا
يَشْتَهُونَ كَمَا فُعِلَ بِأَشْيَاعِهِمْ مِنْ قَبْلُ إِنَّهُمْ كَانُوا
فِي شَكٍّ مُرِيبٍ
And if you could see when they are terrified but there is no escape,
and they will be seized from a place nearby * And they will [then]
say, 'We believe in it!' But how for them will be the taking [of
faith] from a place far away? * And they had already disbelieved in it
before and would assault the unseen from a place far away * And
prevention will be placed between them and what they desire, as was
done with their kind before. Indeed, they were in  suspicious
(disquieting) doubt. [34:51-54]

It is a Hadeeth from Imam Sadiq PBUH saying that the human being has no way to know God, so to believe in Him and submit toward Him, but It is the God who will introduce Himself to everyone and we are only expected to accept Him when He did so to us. This is related to what is calld Fitrah (الفطرة) in Quran and Hadeeth:

فَأَقِمْ وَجْهَكَ لِلدِّينِ حَنِيفًا فِطْرَةَ اللَّهِ الَّتِي فَطَرَ
النَّاسَ عَلَيْهَا لَا تَبْدِيلَ لِخَلْقِ اللَّهِ ذَلِكَ الدِّينُ
الْقَيِّمُ وَ لَكِنَّ أَكْثَرَ النَّاسِ لَا يَعْلَمُونَ
So direct your face toward the religion, inclining to truth. [Adhere
to] the fitrah of Allah upon which He has created [all] people. No
change should there be in the creation of Allah. That is the firm
religion, but most of the people do not know [30:30]

The firm religion, a consequence of having a healthy heart and so being always confronted to Fitrah through that heart, is stable with respect to any possible disturbance and perturbation. Philosophical reasoning to overcome mental obstacles are good, but this is the right path for everyone, be it educated or not, old or young, genius or regular, man or woman, with any race or historical/cultural/religious background, in any section of history, and etc. as "لَا تَبْدِيلَ لِخَلْقِ اللَّهِ" which means "no change should there be in the creation of Allah".
So now, "Can you be Muslim even if you struggle to believe there is a god?", simply yes if you try to be a normal good man, not letting your desires control your life, but you control your life based on morals you know to be valid, and wait for Allah to introduce Himself to you, if He has not done yet which I doubt. Allah introduces Himself in several different occasions, when one is hopelessly worried about his/her child being badly sick, when his/her life is in danger and sees no one/thing to trust on, and etc. ... Just review your own life history to find the remarks ... I had my own, and believe me, He never stops after one single such introduction ...


I can proof you that there is God. And I can also answer your questions. the point is All of my answers are based on "Jafari" religion (Shi'ism).

The first answer to your question is the Base of Islam is to believe there is God. so you Need to believe in Tawhid before believe in Islam. (Tawhid says God exists, and God is unique. Nobody and Nothing is like him and He is actually full with all good qualities.)

So, for proofing that God exists, First we need to believe in "We exist.". yes. this is one of big problems of some philosophers. If you don't believe in this, you can tell me in comments.

The second step is to believe in:

All things around us needs a creator for being.

For example, a human needs a father and a mother for his/her creation. Also, a computer needs a scientist for making theories and a factory to be created. If you see around yourself, all thing MUST have a creator. nothing can create itself.

The third step is to believe in:

Nothing in this world can create everything. but everything is created!

think about this. you see many things around yourself and you believe somebody was created it before. so the creators of all things need some creators themselves! If you think about it, you will believe in somebody must exists to create everything. because nothing can create itself! right? So can you find anybody in this world who can create everything? (or basically create first raw materials)?
So, this point needs to be talked more. For example, I have a pen. my pen is created by a factory. this factory is built by some workers. those workers need some parents. all parents need parents and so on. so finally who created all of these? (or basically, the first people?)

Now, we can believe in he who is called "God"!
who Exists basically by its nature, who don't need anybody else to create him, who can create everything because he is super-powerful! who created all things even "Time" and "Space"! yes, that's true! Time and Space are things that exist, and need a creator like everything else!
These are the basics of "Tawhid". I tried to tell you them easy. Many reasons are exist that can proof the existence of God, So you can tell me if you are interested in these reasons and talks.
At the end, Welcome to Islam :)
